# What package do I need to install to use React js in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, visual-studio-2015

How do we setup the Reactjs environment in visual studio 2013 and above?

Comment: http://reactjs.net/getting-started/download.html#development-builds

Comment: you can use nuget to fetch reactjs.net for mvc and use babel in bundleConfig if youre using jsx